# How would I decode this XOR Cipher

Tags: encryption, security, xor

I have been given a XOR Cipher which is a bunch of hexidecimal looking charcters. This cipher is:

```
fa ce fd d3 fa df ed d3 fa ce d3 d3 fa de df d3  
fa de df d3 fa de f9 d3 fa ce f9 d3 fa de f1 d3   
fa e1 ed d3 f9 ce fd d3 f9 ce fd d3 f9 ce f5 d3   
f9 ce fd d3 fa de f9 d3 fa de d3 d3 fa e1 ed d3  
f9 ce ed d3 fa de f1 d3 f9 ce f1 d3 fa de ed 89
```

I'm not quite sure how to decode this and if I need to flip this cipher in any way.

Comment: I don't think this is a cypher, it looks more like a stream of updates for a 4 byte value. The value changes but is consistent. Maybe some kind of sensor information?